# AngularJS Navigation does not work after tinymce directive

Tags: javascript, tinymce, angularjs

I have problem I can't figure out but I do have a hint. Before integrating TinyMCE the main navigation was working fine eg links Settings, Analytics, Setup; it isn't working now if you click them.

Here is my js file:

```
var app_htmleditor_module = angular.module('app_htmleditor', ['components']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {templateUrl: getBaseURL()+'public/tpl/app/htmleditor.htm',   controller: HtmlEditorCtrl, reloadOnSearch:false }).
            otherwise( {redirectTo: '/'});
    }
]);
    
angular.module('components', []).directive('imageUpload', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
              uploaderid:'@uploaderid'
            },
        templateUrl: '/public/tpl/imageupload.htm'
    }
});
        
app_htmleditor_module.directive('uiTinymce', function() {
     return {
         
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
             
             element.tinymce({
                 // Location of TinyMCE script
                 script_url: 'http://resources.holycrap.ws/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                 // General options
                 theme: "simple",

                 // Change from local directive scope -> "parent" scope
                 // Update Textarea and Trigger change event
                 // you can also use handle_event_callback which fires more often
                 onchange_callback: function(e) {

                     if (this.isDirty()) {
                         this.save();

                         // tinymce inserts the value back to the textarea element, so we get the val from element (work's only for textareas)
                         //ngModel.$setViewValue(e.getBody().innerHTML);
                         ngModel.$setViewValue(element.val());
                         scope.$apply();
                         
                         return true;
                     }
                 }
             });

         }
     }
});
```

And I added above tinymce directive into textarea using `ui:tinymce` like this:

```
<textarea ui:tinymce ng-model="data.html_tab" id="{{fileUploaderID}}_html_tab" name="{{fileUploaderID}}_html_tab" style="width:600px; height:300px"></textarea>
```

Notice `ui:tinymce` above. If I remove that, the navigation works fine again. So how do I make my navigation work with `ui:tinymce` added in textarea?

**DEMO URL:**

http://dev-socialapps.rkm-group.com/app/htmleditor/index#/

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

### Update:

As suggested, I added ui js file to my template file first:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/master/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
```

Then In my js file, I added:

```
var app_htmleditor_module = angular.module('app_htmleditor', ['components', 'ui']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: getBaseURL()+'public/tpl/app/htmleditor.htm',
                controller: HtmlEditorCtrl,
                reloadOnSearch:false
            }).
            otherwise( {redirectTo: '/'});
    }
]);

app_htmleditor_module.value('ui.config', {
   tinymce: {
      theme: 'simple'
   }
});
```

And in textarea tag:

```
<textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="tinymce" id="{{fileUploaderID}}_html_tab" name="{{fileUploaderID}}_html_tab" style="width:600px; height:300px"></textarea>
```

But I am getting error:

```
ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
```

Though ui js file is added fine, I confirmed by viewing source code and clicking on link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the latest version of the tinymce directive in the angular-ui library?

[Demo](http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-tinymce)

[JS file](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/build/angular-ui.js)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure I just took example code from here: http://jsfiddle.net/ProLoser/nTzRA/light/

Comment: I am just using this file nothing else (eg no ui): `angular-1.0.1.js`

Comment: Well try it with the latest version, hopefully that will work.  The version you found may be out of date/not working anymore.  To quickly test, just add `<script src="https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/master/build/angular-ui.js"></script>` to your HTML and edit your module declaration to add `ui` to your app: `angular.module('myApp', ['ui']);`.  Then you can try doing ui-tinymce like in the example.

Comment: Tried that but am getting error, please see updated question with details

Comment: Ah, make sure you include the tinymce js file too. `<script src="https://raw.github.com/tinymce/tinymce/master/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_dev.js"></script>`

Comment: That url gives back 404 error :( Previously I tried adding `https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/master/modules/directives/tinymce/src/tinymce.js` but with that still same error

Comment: After adding `angular.module('ui.filters', []); angular.module('ui.directives', []); angular.module('ui', ['ui.filters', 'ui.directives']).value('ui.config', {});` the error is gone but textarea doesn't have tinymce applied. I am using this file for tinymce: https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/master/modules/directives/tinymce/src/tinymce.js

Comment: If you could reproduce the problem in a smaller footprint, it would help to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Yes issue was outdated tinymce directive, fixed, thanks for the help :)